# Aviso: "Nenhuma aplicação local foi fornecida. Você pode defini-la no menu Executar, Parametros" Problema de Criação de DLL Dinâmico em C++ no DEV++

Tags: c, c++, dll, dinâmico

Estou tentando criar uma DLL com o código que o professor passou, mas ele não compila corretamente. Fica aparecendo o aviso:

> "Nenhuma aplicação local foi fornecida. Você pode defini-la no menu Executar, Parâmetros"

1. O que seria esses `Parâmetros` que devo colocar?
2. Neste caso que eu quero mostrar o `HelloWord` na tela, eu teria que criar um arquivo `.dll` em um editor de texto e colocar dentro dele `HelloWord`? E aí então compilá-lo?

Segue o DLL da main:

```
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;
 typedef void (*MyFunc)(void);

 /* run this program using the console pauser or add 
  your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

 int main(int argc, char** argv) {

     HINSTANCE hinst;
     MyFunc Hello;
     hinst = LoadLibrary("MyDLL.dll");
     if (!hinst)
     {
         MessageBox(0,"DLL File not found!", "Error", MB_ICONERROR);
         exit(0);
     }

     Hello = (MyFunc)GetProcAddress(hinst,"HelloWorld");
     Hello();
     FreeLibrary(hinst);
     exit(0);

     return 0;
}
```

Segue o DLL da função:

```
#ifndef _DLL_H
#define _DLL_H

#if BUILDING_DLL
#define DLLIMPORT _declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLIMPORT _declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DLLIMPORT void HelloWord();

#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que você está tentando rodar o projeto da DLL.

Você precisa criar dois projetos:

- um projeto do tipo **DLL** onde você vai colocar o código da sua função HelloWorld() no arquivo dllmain.cpp;
- e um projeto do tipo **Console Application** onde você vai colocar a código da função main() no arquivo main.cpp.

Crie os projetos no mesmo diretório.